# Sharing User Information Across Clients Secured With Identity Server

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am creating a .NET Core solution based on the [IdentityServer ASP.NET Identity](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity) quickstart. I am using separate projects for an IdentityServer, an API, and an SPA client. Authentication works fine, but I have a question regarding overall system architecture best practices and sharing data between the IdentityServer and API projects.

Suppose I have the following simplified data schema in my solution:

```
class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FavoriteColor { get; set; }
}

class SomeObject
{
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }

    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
}
```

Now suppose UserA creates a creates an account (and a `User` record) with the IdentityServer, logs in with hybrid flow, and retrieves an access_token that can be used to authenticate with the API. UserA then calls the some `API/some objects` endpoint on the API that should return a list of all the `SomeObject`s. The SPA will display the list of `SomeObject` to UserA, including the `SomeObject.Owner.FavoriteColor` property for each object.

In order to return the `SomeObject.Owner.FavoriteColor` data, the API needs access to the `User` store. So, my question is this: what is the recommended way to share `User` data between the IdentityServer and the API? Should the API have access to the same user data the IdentityServer uses? Should each use the same database, and IdentityServer simply uses the `User` table and the API uses both the `User` and `SomeObject` tables?

Basically, in the IdentityServer, API, and SPA architecture, how does the database fit in? One shared? Are there two? If best practice is to not sure the User store with the API, do I need an additional data model to store user info on the API?

Thanks.

Comment: IdentityServer just handles authentication/authorization. It is not a user management system. If you authenticate with a flow that utilizes the user (i.e. not something like client auth, as clients are not the same thing as users), you will get back a user id. You can then use this user id to make appropriate changes in your database/look up the user via that id from your database. So, yes, generally, both systems will need access to the database.

Comment: I'd love to hear more peoples thoughts on this one, or a more fleshed out answer. I'm more interested in the scenario where identity server is standalone with it's own database and the API somehow also stores it's users in a table of it's own, again in a separate database.

Maybe after authentication on the identity server end, a call is made from identity server to the API creating the user via a post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do one of two things.

1.) Create a new Project to encapsulate the User manager interactions and business logic. Include this as a NuGet package to your API and IdentityServer4 implementation.

2.) Create a new User Manager API that your current API would use to get the user details and have the new API consume the Nuget package from #1.